# Rapid Development framework/tools for PHP / MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, angularjs, codeigniter, zend-framework2

I'm coming from a classic ASP / MSSQL background.
.NET seems way too big and bloated for me and I am looking for suggestions for a new framework in PHP, but staying with MSSQL for database.

I believe in developing the data structure first and much of the business logic is in Stored Procedures in the database.

I would like to quickly develop "pretty" single-page/AJAX CRUD apps with Javascript frameworks, client and server side validation. I have researched different frameworks (zend, cakephp, codeigniter) and am very confused. I am not sure which has the quickest learning curve and can quickly generate pages with basic functionality based off our data structures. I still want to be able to customize things at any level - but I would trade this off somewhat for rapid development.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://laravel.com/ is an awesome framework to build php REST applications so quickly...

Comment: Looks nice. Any suggestions on getting started?

Comment: There is a good tutorial from Andrew Perk that you can refer to learn in a step by step http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Jmh9JKnyQ